# How do i generate Remove from cart Url for a product ? (Magento)

Tags: magento

Is it possible to create "Remove from cart" Url for a product with a custom function, so that i can place that function in my custom block which allows user to remove an item from cart...

Comment: please complete your question. What would like to do? Do you want an url to remove from cart?

Comment: @ Oğuz, i want to have "remove item from cart url" in my custom block..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you examine, app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php and find the method: getDeleteUrl() will offer some insight on how its generated:

```
/**
 * Get item delete url
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDeleteUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl(
        'checkout/cart/delete',
        array(
            'id'=>$this->getItem()->getId(),
            Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => $this->helper('core/url')->getEncodedUrl()
        )
    );
}
```

You can find the call to this in template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml:

`<td class="a-center"><a href="<?php echo $this->getDeleteUrl()?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove item')?>" class="btn-remove btn-remove2"><?php echo $this->__('Remove item')?></a></td>`

With this info you should be able to create a new controller action for the cart to simply remove a specific ID to a product in the cart's index.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me is going directly to the source:

add:

```
Mage::getUrl( 'checkout/cart/add', array( 'id' => $item->getId() ) );
```

edit:

```
Mage::getUrl( 'checkout/cart/configure', array( 'id' => $item->getId() ) );
```

delete:

```
Mage::getUrl( 'checkout/cart/delete', array( 'id' => $item->getId() ) );
```

Comment: hi @Beshoy Girgis Where i put this code controller or model or view

Comment: Works perfect for me in 1.8 and 1.9

Answer (score 4):

Where `$_item` is a `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract` object:

```
$renderer = new Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer();
$renderer->setItem($_item);
$renderer->getDeleteUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest work out after combining different answers

Add this to the top of file lists.phtml(template/catlog/product)

```
<?php 
//getting cart count
$currentDelete = array();
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
        if($item->getProductId()){
            $currentDelete[$item->getProductId()] =  Mage::getUrl( 'checkout/cart/delete', array( 'id' => $item->getId() ) );
        }
    }
?>
```

After

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
```

Add this

```
       <?php 
            if (isset($currentDelete) and array_key_exists($_product->getId(), $currentDelete)) { ?>
            <div class="curCart">
            <a href=" <?php echo $currentDelete[$_product->getId()]; ?>">Remove</a> 
            </div>
            <?php }?>
```